# Is there a Haskell module for compiling metadata into my packages

Tags: haskell, version, metadata

I've successfully used the [GitHash module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/githash-0.1.4.0/docs/GitHash.html) to bake things like the branch name and commit hash into programs.

Are there any other, similar, modules for extracting data from `package.yaml` in a similar way? (I guess TemplateHaskell is involved?) Specifically, for the moment, I'm interested in the version string, but a wider-reaching solution would be potentially very useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a special module that contains a packages own version, among other things: `Paths_*pkgname*` ([link to the relevant section of Cabal's documentation](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-package.html#accessing-data-files-from-package-code)).

> The `Paths_pkgname` module also includes some other useful functions and values, which record the version of the package and some other directories which the package has been configured to be installed into (e.g. data files live in `getDataDir`):
>
> ```hs
> version :: Version
>
> getBinDir :: IO FilePath
> getLibDir :: IO FilePath
> getDynLibDir :: IO FilePath
> getDataDir :: IO FilePath
> getLibexecDir :: IO FilePath
> getSysconfDir :: IO FilePath
> ```